# HttpPost error 204 ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest

I have created an API with 5 controllers as part of my room reservation API. The API can handle the creation of new rooms, reservations, users, companies, employees.

I am using:

- VS 2019, ASP.NET Core 3.1
- SQL Server
- EF version 5
- SwaggerUI

Every http request is working properly except for the post method which is giving an error 204. When I create any user, room, reservation, employee or company I keep getting this error, and when I request the `GET` method no data is written in the database.

This is the code for one of my post methods (`RoomController.cs`):

```cs
[HttpPost("CreateNewRoom")]
public async Task<ActionResult<RoomResource>> CreateRoom([FromBody] SaveRoomResource saveRoomResource)
{
   var validator = new SaveRoomResourceValidator();
   var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(saveRoomResource);

   if (!validationResult.IsValid)
       return BadRequest(validationResult.Errors);     

   var roomToCreate = _mapper.Map<SaveRoomResource, Room.core.Room.core.Models.Room>(saveRoomResource);

   var newRoom = await _roomService.CreateRoom(roomToCreate);
   var room = await _roomService.GetRoomById(newRoom.Id);
   var roomResource = _mapper.Map<Room.core.Room.core.Models.Room, RoomResource>(room);

   return Ok(roomResource);
}
```

In `startup.cs`, more specifically in `ConfigureServices()`, I added this:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var noContentFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (noContentFormatter != null)
    {
        noContentFormatter.TreatNullValueAsNoContent = false;
    }
});
```

For reference, this is my `SaveRoomResource.cs` code:

```
public class SaveRoomResource
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Any help on how to fix such error could be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You're using an unsupported runtime and EF Core version .NET Core 3.1 *and* .NET 5 have reached End Of Life. .NET 5 was never a Long Term Support version anyway. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until November 2024

Comment: `204` is a success code anyway. Why do you assume that's an error?

Comment: HTTP *204 No Content* success status response code indicates that a request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to navigate away from its current page. [Details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204).

Comment: Status codes aside, are you certain that `_roomService` behaves as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpNoContentOutputFormatter` class status code to 204 if the content is `null`. I think you are setting this in configure service method and your roomResourcce might be null and hence `204` status code.